# How to write a sql query to get following result from 1 table?

Tags: sql

How to write a query to get the following output:

[image]

Main Table/ source table:
[image]

Comment: Please share what you tried and what didn't work.

Comment: I removed the extraneous database tags.  Feel free to add the tag for the database you are actually using.

Comment: Please see: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: And take a [tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour).

Comment: Here is a guide on posting T-SQL related questions: http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/

Answer (score 1):

Here is one method that uses `union all` and aggregation:

```
select weeknumber, sum(opened) as opened, sum(closed) as closed
from ((select OpenWeekNumber as weeknumber, 1 as Opened, 0 as Closed
       from maintable
      ) union all
      (select ClosedWeekNumber as weeknumber, 0 as Opened, 1 as Closed
       from maintable
       where ClosedWeekNumber > 0
      )
     ) t
group by weeknumber
order by weeknumber;
```